# What does "/" mean in R when writing a regression formula in lm()

Tags: r, lm

The formula is just like this. I don't quite understand the usage of the notion "/". It seems that "/" usually be used in dummy variables. But I am not sure about its usage.

```
lm(y~x/z,data = data.frame(x = rnorm(6), y = rnorm(6), z = rep(0:1,each=3)))
```

Comment: I think you are suggesting here at first the mathemical operation occurs of x being divided by z, and that the result of that calculation is used as a predictor variable in the regression model. That is not correct though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`lm(y ~ x/z, data)` is just a shortcut for `lm(y ~ x + x:z, data)`

These two give the same results:

```
lm(mpg ~ disp/hp,data = mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp/hp, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp      disp:hp  
  2.932e+01   -3.751e-02   -1.433e-05  


lm(mpg ~ disp + disp:hp, data = mtcars)

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + disp:hp, data = mtcars)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp      disp:hp  
  2.932e+01   -3.751e-02   -1.433e-05
```

So, what your doing is modelling `mpg` based on `disp` alone and on an interaction between `disp` and `hp`.

Comment: Link to the official documentation [Defining statistical models; formulae](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Formulae-for-statistical-models)